# Length of intervals formed by union of $\{x: \frac{-c+z_1}{z_2}<x<\frac{c+z_1}{z_2} \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

what is the length of the intervals of the form $\{x: \frac{-c+z_1}{z_2}<x<\frac{c+z_1}{z_2} \}$ where $c$ is some constant and $z_1\in \{1,....N_1\}$ and $z_2\in \{1,....N_2\}$. In other words what is the measure of the set 
\begin{align}
A=\bigcup_{z_1\in \{1,....N_1\},z_2\in \{1,....N_2\}}\{x: \frac{-c+z_1}{z_2}<x<\frac{c+z_1}{z_2} \}
\end{align}

**What I did.**

The length of the single interval is $l_n=\frac{2c}{z_2}$.  So, we can over bound the length by $ \sum_{z_1\in \{1,....N_1\}} \sum_{z_2\in \{1,....N_2\}} \frac{2c}{z_2} \le 2cN_1(1+\ln N_2)$.

However, this bound is not accurate since there are overlaps between intervals.  Is there a better way to approach this problem? thanks